The “AI search” on the Math Stack Exchange (and other site with MathJax) can’t show MathJax properly
I hate the AI search, but I still want to point out a thing:



The search can’t show the MathJax formatting properly, the AI search has the “$$” thing, so it means that the search can’t show the equation properly.
And see the example below:



What’s the point the search can’t even formatting MathJax properly? I think the search is quite useless.
If we need to read the content on the AI search, we need to click the question/answer.

Closing this one as I've answered the more direct question of "was the test officially announced". But yeah, should've never happened :)
